# Using Code First can I set a default parameter in a table/model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF6.1 and the Code First process I am designing my classes first and then migrating them to my DB using Migrations. 
One of the fields in my class is "CreateDate" which I would like to have the DB default the current date into when creating the record.

I have set the field to

```
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

but that doesn't do it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it's not easy.  It requires the use of Migrations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621

Look under the heading: **Customizing Migrations**

Once the migration code is generated, you can modify it to add a default value.  Just make sure to write the equivalent Down action as appropriate.

Example:

```
AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "DateCreated", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GetDate()"));
```

Comment: I am primarily doing it this way for the migrations feature so this works out well.

Comment: Unfortunately this only allows me to put a value in that corresponds with the datatype. What I need to do is put in "GetDate()" so that it puts in the record create date.

Comment: While I haven't used it myself, try replacing the use of defaultValue with defaultValueSql.  It takes a string that I believe will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: defaultValueSQL did it.  Thanks